# TS2683 (TS) 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation

Tags: typescript

I'm facing this problem with TypeScript file and would like to know how to fix this.

For now I have suppressed this typescript exception but would like to learn how to address this. The following is my code:

```
export class BaseResult {
    isSuccessful: boolean;
    totalRecords: number;
    successMessage: string;
    reasonForFailure: string;
    lastExecutedDateTime: Date;
}

export class Result<T> extends BaseResult {
    data: T;
}

export class CollectionResult<T> extends BaseResult {
    data: T[];
}

export class PagedCollectionResult<T> extends CollectionResult<T> {
    pageNumber: number;
    pageSize: number;
    filter: string;

    pages = function () {
        return (this.totalRecords <= 0 || this.pageSize <= 0) ? 0 : Math.ceil(this.totalRecords / this.pageSize);//<--All the **this** keyword shows the error
    }
}
```

Comment: Replace `pages = function () {` with `pages() {`

Comment: change for arrow function: *pages = () =>*

Comment: class syntax doesn't need the `function` or `()=>` notation to declare a method.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As some of the comments indicated, your `this` reference is not typed because you are using the `function () {}` syntax to define your function. The `this` object inside such a function will inherently be of type `any` , because `this` will be the caller of the function (unknowable at design-time).

If you change your syntax to an arrow function, like

```
pages = () => {
```

or simply omit the function keyword and arrow altogether, like

```
pages() {
```

then the `this` object inside the function will reference the class instance `this` instead of type `any`.

See [the TypeScript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this) for more explanation.

Comment: Note that if you really need a caller-specified `this` (e.g. your function will be called by a framework that sets `this` to something sensible), you can tell TypeScript the type of `this` by introducing a fake `this` parameter: `callback = function (this: HTMLElement) { … }`

Answer (score 18):

Use explicit `this` annotation:

```js
pages = function(this: BaseResult) {
```

In this context, `this` is not an argument to the function but the actual place to declare the type of `this`, see the handbook:

> The JavaScript specification states that you cannot have a parameter
> called this, and so TypeScript uses that syntax space to let you
> declare the type for this in the function body.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#declaring-this-in-a-function

Comment: I'm using this (as I'm passing the function to a 3rd party library). It fixes my initial problem but now eslint is unhappy
`error  Parsing error: Unexpected keyword 'this'`
There is no rule referenced that I can override to allow it. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is your function are some class method? For free functions `this` annotation cause error