# Vue Typescript callback: this implicitly has type any

Tags: typescript, vue.js, compiler-construction, debouncing

When using anonymous function with lodash debounce in my vue component for watch option, I got the typescript compiler error "this implicityly has type any.

Here is my component

```js
export default defineComponent({
  data(){
    return {
       filters:{
          filter1: "foo"
       } as Record<string, string>
    }
  },
  methods:{
    load(){
       //load function
    }
  },
  watch:{
    "filters":{
       deep: true,
       handler:_debounce(function(newValue){
           this.load() // <= hear I got "this implicitly has type any"
       }, 500)
    }
  }
})
```

I found on this post to use arrow function for my anonymous debounce callback function but the error still persists ([TS2683 (TS) 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48007891/ts2683ts-this-implicitly-has-type-any-because-it-does-not-have-a-type-ann))

Another solution is to pass "this: any" as an argument to the function, but I found this very ugly.

```js
_debounce(function(this:any, newValue){
           this.load() // <= hear I got "this implicitly has type any"
       }, 500)
```

Is there a better solution to handle this issue? (without setting noImplicitAny to false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using 'arrow' function definition, to keep the scope of `this`.

```
handler:_debounce(() => {
       this.load() 
   }, 500)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

EDIT:
For this case, some design limitation in typescript makes it difficult to detect/assign a type to implicit `this` (see
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38845#issuecomment-651455328)
It should work using a function expression with typed parameter, defined in a custom Interface, for example:

```
interface ComponentInterface {
  load(): void
}
```

And then:

```
_debounce(function(this:ComponentInterface, newValue){
       this.load()
   }, 500)
```

You can find several cases of defining types/annotations using this way at  https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#using-with-options-api

Comment: When I use arrow function I got an "object is possibly undefined" on this and if I do "this?.load()" I got "Property 'load' does not exist on type 'never'.
It does not solve the issue :(

Comment: I've added some comments/references and example for this case, please try it and let me know if it works for you

Comment: Thanks! it was what I was looking for. I wanted to be sure there was no other solution than this